# UITextView scrolling issue when image is added as a subview

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a fixed size UITextView and if I add more word's, it will scroll to it's content. I'm adding an UIImage as a subview in UITextView. If there are more comment's I cannot scroll UITextView to see the image. Can we set the content height of uitextview to solve this issue?[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: You could fix by using the **self.textView.textInputView.frame** but there is a issue that text will get hidden by imageView if you add it. So better option would be if you go for UICollectionView or scrollView as it would help you in achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` is not designed to receive a subview like that, and it won't scroll it correctly. You need to add both as subviews in a `UIScrollView`, which should auto-behave like so:

- Swiping should first scroll the view where the touchDown event began (i.e., your `UITextView`)
- When that view has no more to scroll, the event should bubble up to the `UIScrollView` itself, bringing up your `UIImage`.

If you don't like this behavior then you can synchronize scrolling as you prefer by calculating the height of your text inside your `UITextView` bounds, using:

```
CGSize size = [myText sizeWithFont:myFont forWidth:myFontWidth.0 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```